# Could it be that the pronoun *eǵh₂om ("I") in PIE is not an innovation?

Tags: proto-indo-european, pronouns, proto-world

I think, it is generally believed that the word for "I" in PIE was an innovation and in more ancient branches the 1st person singular pronoun was similar to the plural one, "min/men".

But if we make a broader comparison, the pronoun tends to look like *ʔine-ge in different language families.

Just to list some:

- Mapucho: in-če
- Akkadian: anaku
- Somali: ani-ga
- Kordofanian: ne-ji
- Chukchi: e-ɣә-
- Proto-Austronesian: i-ka-
- Proto-Pama-Nyungan: nga-
- Mojave: ʔiɲe-č
- Yahi: aini-ci

etc.

So, can we say that *ʔine-ge pronoun could be at least as old as *min?

P.S. More:

- Beni Sheko (Nilo-Sakharian) ıŋgi
- Nyalgulgule (Nilo-Sakharian) aŋgi
- Ngalakan (Sahul) ŋaykːa
- Korean: neugi

Comment: Is there any similarity between those pronouns and the PIE one except "has a velar in it"?

Comment: @Draconis not much, actually, I agree. But between themselves they are similar. In Mapucho če means "person".

Comment: In that case, the title and the body seem to be asking different questions. The title is asking about PIE *_eǵh₂om_ and the body is asking about a bunch of other languages that don't look much like that.

Comment: @Draconis the older form of *eǵh₂om is *eǵ, so it can be connected to the rest (see the Chukchi version). The thing is, it seems, *min is not the sole most ancient reconstructible first-person pronoun, even in Eurasiatic.

Comment: At which point we're back to, I don't see any similarity between those pronouns and the PIE one except "has a velar in it".

Answer (score 1):

> I think, it is generally believed that the word for "I" in PIE was an innovation

The most usual opinion is that internal reconstruction of a proto language and reconstruction beyond a significant time depth is unreliable.

- Sihler (1995): "The similarities are obvious, but the precise paradigms of the parent speech are very difficult to reconstruct." (§ 360) And though he recognizes the possibility deriving **eǵHóm* from **éǵoH* plus **mé* or even **Hmé, it seems inconsequential for Homeric Greek εγον.

  > The **astute** proposal has been made that the etymon of the classical (and Germanic?) forms represents the innovation: that *eǵom (not *eǵHom<sup>1</sup>) is composed of *\om* '1st person", seen in the verb endings *-mi, *-m̥, and in the oblique stems of the 1st person pronoun (as seen in 363), plus an atonic deictic element seen elsewhere in such elements as G γε, γα, Go. *mik* [...]. The **eǵō of the classical languages in this view is a remodeling [...]

  > (Sihler 1995, pg. 369)

  The fn. 1 offers alternatively **éǵ-Hom*, with **h₁mé on the basis of ἐμ-.
- Ringe (2007) doesn't even mention **eǵHom* because it plays no role in Germanic, but for the pronouns in general he refers the reader to Sihler (1995) and ''especially'' Katz (1998), which is not available to me.
- Beekes (EDG, cf. έγω) seems to prefer analogy: "Were the variants **h₁egō*, **h₁eǵh₁om* reshaped after the 1sg. verbal endings *-ō* (thematic), *-om* (secondary), or is *-om* a particle which is frequent in Old Indic (cf. *t<sub>u</sub>vám* etc.)?"
- Kapovi (2017) argues similarly (p. 82; emphasis mine):

  > The 1 sg. pronoun showed the suppletivity of **h₁eǵ-* (nom.) and **m-* (oblique). The
  > oblique cases had both stressed and clitic forms. Three nom. forms are reconstructable,
  > one non-derived (**h₁eǵ*) and two with suffixes, the **-oh₂* one perhaps being dialectal. The existence of two (even three) parallel forms may not be as strange as it might seem ([...]), cf. Hitt. *ūk* and *ukel, ukila* ‘I, myself’. Hitt. oblique *amm-* (cf. acc. *ammuk* ‘me’), Arm. *i-* (cf. acc. *is* ‘me’), and Gr. ɛ̓- in stressed forms (cf. acc. ɛ̓μέ but clitic μɛ) would point to **h₁m-* (p. 48), not **m-*. However, this is **not in accord** with the glottogonic, but **nonetheless persuasive, connection of pronominal **me-* with verbal eventive 1 sg. **-m*, 1 pl. **-me*** (p. 93). Thus, it is perhaps better to assume that this **h₁m-* is innovative – an analogy [...]. However, **h₁m-* would formally also work for PIE.

This survey is of course not exhaustive. NB: Lundquist and Yates (2018) simply avoid the issue, but help remind of another interesting bit: "For some of these
idiosyncrasies [*of pronomial inflection*] internal reconstructions have been proposed: the affix **-sm-* might be the numeral ‘one’ **sem-*, and on that basis (and with more daring) fem. *-sy-* might have arisen via deletion of **m* in pre-PIE ***-sm-y-* (Ringe 2006: 55)." (ch. 2.2.1)

See, they agree on hardly anything, not the laryngeals anyway.  Note, @anixx has once commented to the effect that some verbal endings look like clitic pronouns, which is not corroborated in these works. Sihler (1995) had only commented "The tonic elements **-wé* and **-mé* seen in several cases do not exactly agree with any nominal element." Also, Yates (2020, 2022) has written on mon-stems.

---

*This answers only a tiny part of the question, though enough to make an answer. Two longer rants I drafted which weren't properly saved by the editor, and it is of course much more difficult to give a positive answer. So I am unlikely going to bring this up again.*

Comment: “Katz (1998)” must be Joshua Katz’ PhD thesis, _Topics in Indo·European Personal Pronouns_, which deals primarily with the first- and second-person plural pronouns, but of course also mentions the singular pronouns sporadically. I have a copy, but I can’t seem to find it available online either.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Katz' thesis is on the 1./2. dual and plural pronouns, not just the plural.

Comment: @Sverre Yes, dual and plural, you’re right – non-singular was my main point.

Comment: Funny you should mention *dual*. The longer part of my answer focused on PIE *\*wi-* / *\*dwis*- "apart", *\*wiHrós* "male" etc. in reference to @anixx comment, “In Mapucho *če* means "person"”. From what I find the (better: a) dual ending is *\*-h1(e)*. Trying to derive 1Sg from dual is a mind bending exercise.